# Understand String as Type Parameter

Tags: java

I do not understand why the below obj of type integer is able to be created with a String type parameter of PPrinter class although The code compiles and run successfully. Please help!

```
class PPrinter<String> {

    private String t;

    PPrinter(String t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    String getT(){
        return this.t;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PPrinter<Integer> obj = new PPrinter<>(100);
        System.out.println(obj.getT());

    }
}
```

Comment: that is not a reference to class String, that is a generic type named "String"

Comment: To elaborate on Tims comment: generic type references can have any legal Java name, but convention dictates that they are almost always named as all-caps capital words, usually with just a single letter (such as the commonly seen `T`). Not following this convention can lead to confusing things like this. Everywhere within the `PPrinter` class `String` doesn't actually reference `java.lang.String` but that generic type.

Comment: Thank you i understand now but what if i wanted my PPrinter class to have strict acceptance of String type only?

Comment: If you want it to use `String` only, remove the type parameter

Comment: then you remove the `<String>` after `class PPrinter`

Comment: If it should *only* accept String, then it is not generic. Just leave out the `<String>` in the class name

Comment: Thank you all of you! I got it now. I am preparing for 1z0-809 exam, hence this question arise which confused me ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a generic type named "String" – it's *valid*, but confusing.

From *"Type Parameter Naming Conventions"* in [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) (my emphasis added below):

> ***By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters**. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: **Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.***

Also from that same reference:

```
The most commonly used type parameter names are:
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

Following those conventions, your `PPrinter` class would look like this:

```
class PPrinter<T> {
    private T t;

    PPrinter(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    T getT() {
        return this.t;
    }
}
```

You would still be able to call it with whatever type (`Integer`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc.) as your code also did, but without the confusion of your original question.

```
PPrinter<Integer> obj1 = new PPrinter<>(100);
PPrinter<String> obj2 = new PPrinter<>("foo");
PPrinter<Boolean> obj3 = new PPrinter<>(false);
```